# PHPMailer_5.2.4 com GMAIL

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail

já vi vários tópicos e sites falando sobre o phpmailer enviando direto pro GMAIL, porem não consigo fazer, aparece o seguinte erro:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 
The following From address failed: ***@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected
```

CODIGO:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ob_start();

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['tel'];
    $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];

    if($_POST['nome'] != '' && $_POST['mensagem'] != ''){
        require("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
        // Inicia a classe PHPMailer

        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        // Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

        $mail->Port = 587;

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        $mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)

        $mail->Username = '***@gmail.com';
        $mail->Password = '***';

        // Define o remetente

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->From = "***@gmail.com"; // Seu e-mail
        $mail->FromName = "Contato Show de Quimica"; // Seu nome

        // Define os destinatário(s)

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        $mail->AddAddress('***@gmail.com');
        $mail->AddReplyTo($email);

        // Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem

        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

        $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
        $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8'; // Charset da mensagem

         // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
        // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        $mail->Subject  = "Mensagem de Contato Show de Quimica"; // Assunto da mensagem
        $mail->Body = "<font style=\"font-size:16px\"><b>Nome:</b> $nome; <br /><b>E-mail:</b> $email; <br /><b>Telefone:</b>$telefone; <br /><br /><b>Mensagem:</b><br />$mensagem</font>";
        $mail->AltBody = "Nome: $nome;\r\n E-mail: $email;\r\n\r\n Mensagem:\r\n $mensagem;\r\n\r\n Telefone:\r\n $telefone";
        // Envia o e-mail

        $enviado = $mail->Send();

        // Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Da uma olhada se é o mesmo problema: http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/473485-resolvidophpmailer-e-gmail/  quando eu fui enviar email pelo gmail tive que usar a porta 468 com ssl e tive que permitir aplicativos menos seguros na minha conta do gmail.

Comment: ja usei tbm essa porta com SSL

Comment: Pronto ja permitir, mas continua do mesmo jeito :(

Comment: Sugiro executar apenas o arquivo de exemplo do PHPMAiler usando o [gmail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/v5.2.14/examples/gmail.phps).
Com esse exemplo você vai poder ver mais informações sobre o erro que está acontecendo. A partir dai você pode consultar a seção de [problemas](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), na wiki do PHPMailer.

Comment: segui esse link e funcionou: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754